# How to automate a powershell process in python?

Tags: python, powershell, automation

I am trying to automate a powershell process in python. This is the process in entirety. The commands I want to automate in python are as such:
'Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\iSCSI Target' -Name AllowLoopBack -Value 1',
'New-IscsiVirtualDisk -Path "ramdisk:testRAM.vhdx" -Size 5GB',
'New-IscsiServerTarget -TargetName targetRAMDisk -InitiatorIds @("IPAddress:10.1.1.200")',
'Add-IscsiVirtualDiskTargetMapping -TargetName targetRAMDisk -DevicePath "ramdisk:testRAM.vhdx"',
'Get-IscsiTarget | Connect-IscsiTarget',
'Get-Disk | Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "disk2" -Confirm:$false'

Here is what I tried:

```
def ramdisk_cmd(cmd,shell):
        temp_cwd = TEMP_DIR
        utl.dumplog(str(cmd))
        process = subprocess.run('Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\iSCSI Target' - 
                                  Name AllowLoopBack -Value 1',
                                 'New-IscsiVirtualDisk -Path "ramdisk:testRAM.vhdx" -Size 5GB',
                                 'New-IscsiServerTarget -TargetName targetRAMDisk -InitiatorIds 
                                  @("IPAddress:10.1.1.200")',
                                 'Add-IscsiVirtualDiskTargetMapping -TargetName targetRAMDisk - 
                                  DevicePath "ramdisk:testRAM.vhdx"',
                                 'Get-IscsiTarget | Connect-IscsiTarget',
                                 'Get-Disk | Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' | Initialize-Disk - 
                                  PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter 
                                  -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS - 
                                  NewFileSystemLabel "disk2" -Confirm:$false'
                                 )
```

I thought this would run the commands that I passed in as strings, but that does not seem to be the case. If I want to automate each of these commands in Python, how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you'll the process you start should be powershell.exe and then pass your commands as command.

```
process = subprocess.run('powershell.exe','-Command','Set-ItemProperty...
```